# how to use c++ ->() operator to get a baseclasses private member? so I can access derived?

Tags: c++, factory

I am attempting to access a derived class `TMAConnection` after receiving it via a baseclass factory method

```
template <>
class cpool::ConnectionPoolFactory<TMAConnection> {
public:
    static std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool> create( const std::uint16_t num_connections, const char* tma_gw_host, const int tma_gw_port) {
        std::vector< std::unique_ptr<cpool::Connection> > connections;

        for ( std::uint16_t k = 0; k < num_connections; ++k ) {
            // cannot use std::make_unique, because constructor is hidden
            connections.emplace_back( std::unique_ptr<TMAConnection>( new TMAConnection{tma_gw_host, tma_gw_port} ) );
        }

        return std::unique_ptr<cpool::ConnectionPool>( new cpool::ConnectionPool{std::move( connections )} );
    }
};
```

My trouble comes trying to access the derived classes functions and members.. such as `TestCPPClient` member, or `querySymbols` function...

```
class TMAConnection final : public cpool::Connection {
public:
    TMAConnection(const char* hostname, const int port){
      this->gateway_host=hostname;
      this->gateway_port=port;

    }
    bool heart_beat() override { return connected; }

    bool is_healthy() override { return connected; }

    bool connect() override {
        connected = true;
        return connected;
    }

    void disconnect() override { 
      connected = false; 
    }

    void querySymbols(std::vector<tmaapi::CD> & empty_contract_vect, std::vector<std::string> & queries_list) {
      this->tma_client.query_matching_tickers(empty_contract_vect, queries_list);
      std::vector<std::string> empty_vec;
    }

    TestCppClient tma_client;

private:
    TMAConnection(){}
    friend cpool::ConnectionPoolFactory<TMAConnection>;
    bool connected = false;
    
    const char* gateway_host;
    int gateway_port;
    uint16_t tma_client_id;
};
```

When I look look at the ConnectionProxy code.. it *seems* i can get the member or derived class with an operator `->` but no avail so far

https://github.com/malikkirchner/connection-pool/blob/master/src/pool.cpp#L61-L63

```
Connection* ConnectionPool::ConnectionProxy::operator->() { return m_connection; }

Connection& ConnectionPool::ConnectionProxy::operator*() { return *m_connection; }
```

Here's where I try to call `create` to get a connection.. but then fail to get my derived class pointer

```
cpool::ConnectionPool::ConnectionProxy proxy_conn = this->tma_conn_pool->get_connection();

proxy_conn->is_healthy(); // this works fine if i don't cast.. since it's in the base class
proxy_conn->querySymbols(empty_contract_vect, sub_batch_vector);  // this fails
```

I tried adding a dynamic cast.. doesn't seem to work

```
    cpool::ConnectionPool::ConnectionProxy proxy_conn = this->tma_conn_pool->get_connection();
    TMAConnection* x = dynamic_cast<TMAConnection*>(&proxy_conn));

    x->is_healthy();
    x->querySymbols(empty_contract_vect, sub_batch_vector); 

/home/server/src/server.cpp:48:64: error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘& proxy_conn’ (of type ‘class cpool::ConnectionPool::ConnectionProxy*’) to type ‘class TMAConnection*’ (source type is not polymorphic)
   48 |     TMAConnection* x = dynamic_cast<TMAConnection*>(&proxy_conn));
```

How can I get a pointer to my derived class?  is my factory wrong?  thank you

EDIT: I tried @typewriters suggestion to use auto .. still didn't work

```
auto proxy_conn = this->tma_conn_pool->get_connection();
TMAConnection* x = dynamic_cast<TMAConnection*>(&proxy_conn));

error: cannot dynamic_cast ‘& proxy_conn’ (of type ‘class cpool::ConnectionPool::ConnectionProxy*’) to type ‘class TMAConnection*’ (source type is not polymorphic)
```

Comment: From https://github.com/malikkirchner/connection-pool/blob/master/test/unit_test.cpp: ```auto pool = ConnectionPoolFactory< TestConnection >::create( 4 );``` ```auto connection = pool->get_connection();```. Have not tried this, but i assume that the connectionpoolfactory should also make TMAconnections

Comment: @typewriter hi, yes in fact it returns ConnectionProxy.. are you saying to try getting `auto` instead of my `cpool::ConnectionPool::ConnectionProxy` ? I based my usage of the library off their `test.cpp` but I can try switching types, thanks for this idea

Comment: @typewriter tried your suggestion and appended the error at the end.. thanks though

Comment: A dynamic cast isn't going to work because the object you are trying to cast is the proxy object.  You can use the `.` operator or `->` operator to get a connection object and I would have expected that SHOULD work.  So why does the `.` operator or `->` operator not work?  Does the `proxy_conn->querySymbols` error just say there is no such method or does it give something useful?

Comment: `get_connection()` returns a `ConnectionProxy`.  You have to call `get_connection()` on the resulting proxy to get the underlying implementation:  `auto proxy = pool.get_connection(); auto* connection = proxy->get_connection();`  You should be able to `dynamic_cast` the `connection` pointer to your derived class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConnectionPool::get_connection()` returns a `ConnectionProxy` which *is not* a `Connection` object directly, but holds one:

A `ConnectionProxy` allows you to access the underlying connection object.

```
// create a pool
auto pool = ...
// get a ConnectionProxy
auto proxy = pool->get_connection();

// cast to your type
if(auto conn = dynamic_cast<TMAConnection*>(proxy.operator->()))
{
    // success!
}
```

Comment: well played.. I had NO clue how to use these damn overloaded operators.  Thank you!